# JS regex pattern for specific case

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched much , but not have much experience with regex patterns and its structure

here's the rules for the pattern

- Ignoring the case sensitive (a or A) is the same , does not matter
- Numbers is accepted but not required > (name) and (name3) and (3name) is accepted
- Only 1 number in the whole word > (name1) is accepted but (name11) is not accepted
- The number cannot be in the middle of the word > (na3me) is not accepted
- No minimum but maximum 12 characters > (namenamenamex) is not accepted
- No special characters is accepted (only characters and numbers) > (#na$me%) is not accepted

if it's hard to have a Regex for all these conditions , anything similar will be appreciated (even if can fit 5 or at least 4 of these conditions)

Comment: @Chilarai there's already an example with each condition

Comment: when you say number cannot be in the middle, do you mean the center or anywhere except the first or last letter. for example is n3ame accepted?

Comment: also not clear is what if you have 2 digits at different positions?  ex: 1name1

Comment: @K4M , I mentioned only 1 number in the whole word , means your example 1name1 should not be accepted

Comment: the reason I asked these two questions was b/c those are the things not covered by @ sean-hay 's answer. just wanted to make sure. but we got a better answer @ flutterish

Comment: @K4M You're absolutely right, the additional clarification was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most compact, but readable:

`^(([0-9][a-zA-Z]{0,11})|([a-zA-Z]{0,11}[0-9])|([a-zA-Z]{1,12}))$`

3 cases:

- digit, 0 to 11 letters
- 0 to 11 letters, digit
- 1 to 12 letters

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(?=.{0,12}$)([0-9]?[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]?)$/
```

This should match it.

- Starts with a positive lookahead to check the string length, between 1 and 12 characters inclusive.
- A single number at the start is optional.
- 1 or more case-insensitive alphanumeric characters in the middle, no special characters accepted.
- Finally, an optional number at the end.

Edit: To satisfy the 1-word-1-number rule, added a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?=.{0,12}$)(?!\d.*\d)(\d?[a-zA-Z]+\d?)$/
```

Comment: Fails on `3name2` ( max 1 digit )

Comment: You solved it , thank you very much - however example like 1name1 accepted which not fit for the third rule , but I'm satisfied with your solution